# "status": 400, "error": "Bad Request", spring boot , Create request

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, postman, http-status-code-400

this is my first time working with spring framwork , and here i was trying to create two table classes and student , with a Many to one relationship , i can't create new student , and i try to , i get a bad request error 400,
thsi is my student entity

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String codeM;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToOne
    private Classes classes;
}
```

and this is the student controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class StudentController {
    final StudentService studentService;

    // create new student
    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody(required = false) Student student) throws Exception {
        if(student == null)
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Student is null");
        Student savedStudent = studentService.create(student);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(savedStudent);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{CodeM}")
    public Student findByCodeM(@PathVariable String CodeM) throws Exception{
        return studentService.findByCodeM(CodeM);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{CodeM}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable String CodeM, @RequestBody Student student) throws Exception{
        if(student == null){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Student is null");
        }
        Student savedStudent = studentService.update(student);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(savedStudent);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<Student> findAll() {
        return studentService.findAll();
    }
}
```

the get Request work , but the POST and Put request Doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

- try below solution in your Model with @ManyToOne variable

  ```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("students")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "classes_id")
    private Classes classes;
  ```

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).